# Software that joins multiple subtitle files that can be synced with video after joining

Tags: video, file-merging, closed-captions

I want to join multiple subtitle files into a single file. The timecode of the 2nd subtitle must continue from the 1st subtitle file's timecode and so on.

I've tried [Easy Subtitle Joiner](http://www.afterdawn.com/software/audio_video/subtitle_tools/easy_subtitles_joiner.cfm), but when I import more than 5 subtitle files in a shot, the time difference between timecode will be big. I also tried others, but it doesn't seems to be a nice joiner software.

Would you recommend a subtitle joiner that can shift time perfectly as it is joining. Because all the subtitle joiner will shift the time lot more as it move on to another subtitle file, this delays the subtitle text that start originally from the next subtitle file. But in overall, I'd like to join multiple subtitle files that actually sync with the video.

Answer (score 1):

If you do not find anything more automated, here is a workaround solution that will work at least for [`.srt` files](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SubRip#SubRip_text_file_format):

You can use [Nikolaj Lynge Olsson's *Subtitle Edit*](http://www.nikse.dk/subtitleedit/) to *first* adjust each file individually to the video - you do *not* have to do this line by line; for each file, just pick one of the first lines and one of the last lines and manually adjust their time of appearance and duration. *Subtitle Edit* can then adjust the rest of the file for you.

Once that is done, you can use the *Tools* -> *Append subtitle* command to join all files in *Subtitle Edit* and save them as a complete subtitle file.

*I am not affiliated with that project. However, I have often used the program for syncing subtitles with little effort.*

Comment: Oh thanks! By the way, the subtitles appeared to be delayed for roughly 50 milisec for each video. Since I'm working with video compilations(~12 videos), the subtitles on the last video theoretically delayed 600 milisec! Well, that's not the program's fault, because I'd tried to create a simple console program to join the subtitles, each timecode has been calculated so precisely, that even I added an extra timecode, which is the duration of the video to the end of the line, so that the "real" end of timecode of a video is specified. But, it still have delays on each video...